# How to get currently logged in user in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm working on an application written in linq. What I want is to get the currently logged in user's email address.

I'm able to get the GUID of that user by

```
string name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

I have a table called **User** and in that table I have 4 columns (UserId, UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserEmail).

What I have done more is I have converted string to GUID

```
Guid guidConverted = new Guid(name);
```

What left is now to compare this **guidConverted** to **UserId** and from there I can get the Email address using **Where** clause.

this is how I'm doing

```
var email = from userName in User
            where userName.UserId== guidConverted
            select userName.UserEmail;
```

but unfortunately I'm not getting any result just **sql query**

Comment: Does this sql query return any result?

Comment: yes it does return a result like
SELECT [t0].[Type], [t0].[UserId], [t0] and so on

Comment: Are you sure you are using LINQ to SQL? That's an outdated, completely deprecated library

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ok but what can I do in order to get the email address of that currently logged in user sir?

Comment: You need to add more details, but you aren't executing the query there. `email` is of type `IQueryable<string>`, you are missing a `.First()` or some other executing statement

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes you were right. I have to wrap my query in () and use .Single();

Answer (score 1):

LINQ has lazy execution. To execute your query, you have to invoke ToList():

```
var query = from userName in User
            where userName.UserId== guidConverted
            select userName.UserEmail;
var email = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `ToList()` is not needed if you have the `.FirstOrDefault()` and sometimes causes performance issues.